# adding python binary distribution to path

Tags: python, installation, package

I am trying to get the python package `simms` to work on my computing cluster. Unfortunately there isn't much documentation. I have
inside my conda env installed it via

```
pip install simms
```

I also git cloned https://github.com/ratt-ru/simms.git to

```
my_dir/simms
```

Then inside my conda env, running the suggested:

```
python my_dir/simms/tests/tests.py
```

gives an error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'casa': 'casa'
```

I have filled the instructions at
https://github.com/ratt-ru/simms/blob/master/tests/test.py to install the
CASA package (from https://casa.nrao.edu/installlinux.shtml) . After
uploading and unzipping, I added it to my path variable with

```
export PATH=$PATH: mydir/casa-6.5.2-26-py3.8
```

Note that `casa-6.5.2-26-py3.8` has a subfolder `bin/` so things Python should know where to look, but I still get the same `FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: did you run `python setup.py install` on clones project ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 No, I have installed the package via pip, the git clone is just so I can run tests, and have access to their data files.

Comment: issue is with casa installation which is not properly done, [installation instruction](https://casadocs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebooks/introduction.html#id1) follow this

Comment: @sahasrara62 hmm, can you elaborate (perhaps with an answer) ; which installation method did you get to work? thanks.